# Cannot read property 'props' of undefined in MUI Select component

Tags: reactjs, select, mui

I'm getting this error as soon as the `<Select>` component loads.
My code:

```
const [x, setX] = useState("");
return (
  <Select
    onChange={v => setX(v)}
    value={x}>
    <MenuItem value={null}></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={10}>10</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={20}>20</MenuItem>
  </Select>
)
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined Select.js:88 
The above error occurred in the <Select> component:
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the initial state used in the `<Select value>` attribute exists as one of the options in `<MenuItem>`

In my case, I was setting `""` as the default value but the default `<MenuItem>` was `null`

Setting both to `null` fixed the issue:

```
const [x, setX] = useState(null);
...
<MenuItem value={null}></MenuItem>
```